# ElasticSearch Java Client querying nested objects

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

How do I convert this kind of query.

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "consultations",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "consultations.prescriptions": "alfuorism"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "consultations.Diagnosis": "Fever"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To a Java Client query using QueryBuilders

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The folowing Java code will generate your query

```
public NestedQueryBuilder nestedBoolQuery(final Map<String, String> propertyValues, final String nestedPath) {

    BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
    Iterator<String> iterator = propertyValues.keySet().iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        String propertyName = iterator.next();
        String propertValue = propertyValues.get(propertyName);
        MatchQueryBuilder matchQuery = QueryBuilders.matchQuery(propertyName, propertValue);
        boolQueryBuilder.must(matchQuery);
    }

    return QueryBuilders.nestedQuery(nestedPath, boolQueryBuilder);
}
```

The parameter `propertyValues` is:

```
Map<String, String> propertyValues = new HashMap<String, String>();
propertyValues.put("consultations.prescriptions", "alfuorism");
propertyValues.put("consultations.Diagnosis", "Fever");
```

The parameter `nestedPath` is:

```
consultations
```

Comment: `propertValue` should be `propertyValue`

Comment: How would this be created if you had more than 2 levels ? For example if it would be something like "xyz.consultations.prescriptions".