# Filter query is not working in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-query

I have document and search query as below elastic is not able to fetch the documents for the matched exception id's initially while creating the index i have done the mapping and after that it is not able to fetch the records

and my mapping looks like below

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "events": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "data": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "comments": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                  "type": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

here is my index document which i am testing against using the search query.

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "score": 1,
  "comments": [{
    "id": "1",
    "type": "Delayed",
```

Comment: If events.recommendationData is a nested field then you need to use nested query.

Comment: i have used nested type i have added the mapping in the question section please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly use query-string on nested fields, You need to use nested query for it

```
GET <index-name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "nested": { --> note
            "path": "events.recommendationData",
            "query": {
              "query_string": {
                "query": "\"1\" OR \"2\"",
                "fields": [
                  "events.recommendationData.exceptionId"
                ],
                "type": "best_fields",
                "default_operator": "or",
                "max_determinized_states": 10000,
                "enable_position_increments": true,
                "fuzziness": "AUTO",
                "fuzzy_prefix_length": 0,
                "fuzzy_max_expansions": 50,
                "phrase_slop": 0,
                "escape": false,
                "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
                "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
                "boost": 1
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 1, --> note, to return documents ,keep 0 for only aggs
  "aggs": {
            "genres": {
                "nested": {
                    "path": "events.recommendationData.recommendations"
                },
                "aggs": {
                    "nested_comments_recomms": {
                        "terms": {
                            "field": "events.recommendationData.recommendations.recommendationType"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: "size": 1, --> note, to return documents 0 for only aggs should it be always 1.

Comment: If you want to see hits , give some value to size. If only aggregations are needed you can give size as 0

Comment: i guess this is for optimization.

Comment: any idea how can i  generate equivalent java code i am trying out the below code but it is not able to generate the same query as above. NestedQueryBuilder queryBuilders = QueryBuilders.nestedQuery("events.recommendationData" ,
                    boolQueryBuilder.filter(QueryBuilders
                    .queryStringQuery(String.join(" OR ", exactMatchThese))
                    .field("events.recommendationData.exceptionId")), ScoreMode.None);

Comment: I haven;t worked with java rest client , below answer can help on it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24710831/elasticsearch-java-client-querying-nested-objects

Comment: For your query in other question Add nested query to filter instead of filter query to nested