# Query from a field of Elasticsearch 7.3 using Java

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

I have the following code working fine and returning the documents. I want to search based on `only one field` from the document and shall return the value of that field from all the documents.

```
        RestHighLevelClient client;

        QueryBuilder matchQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("elon");
        SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
        sourceBuilder.query(matchQueryBuilder);
        sourceBuilder.from(0);
        sourceBuilder.size(10);
        sourceBuilder.timeout(new TimeValue(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
        SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(ELASTIC_SEARCH_INDEX);
        searchRequest.source(sourceBuilder);
        SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

I need it to search only `Name` field and return the value of that field from all documents that returned in this search.

let say, I query `Elon` and it should response a `List<String>`
"lily Elon musk", "parker Elon ",Elon musk 77" and ignore other fields.

**Mapping**

```
{
students: {
mappings: {
properties: {
students: {
properties: {
courseTitle: {
type: "text",
fields: {
keyword: {
type: "keyword",
ignore_above: 256
}
}
},
courseCode: {
type: "text",
fields: {
keyword: {
type: "keyword",
ignore_above: 256
}
}
},
name: {
type: "text",
fields: {
keyword: {
type: "keyword",
ignore_above: 256
}
}
},
courseGrade: {
type: "text",
fields: {
keyword: {
type: "keyword",
ignore_above: 256
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
```

Sample document

```
students: [
{
courseCode: " HM101",
courseTitle: "ICP",
courseGrade: "A"
},
{
courseCode: " CS101",
courseTitle: "electronice",
courseGrade: "B+"
},
{
name: "elon musk"
}]
```

Comment: Provide us your queyString and connection establishment.

Comment: @Gibbs check updated Qs.

Comment: Check my answer and let me know. Hope it ll help you

Comment: Have you tried that? Any luck?

Comment: @Gibbs the links that you have provided are 5 years old. Now a lot of methods deprecated.

Comment: My bad. I updated links. I don't see any change related to the use case of this question.

Comment: @Gibbs where are the links.?

Comment: I meant the links in the answer, not in the comments. And moreover, you have a nested document [type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) and `students` is nested type which has three objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with

```
        String[] includeFields = new String[]{"students.name"};
        sourceBuilder.fetchSource(includeFields, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need it to search only Name field and return the value of that field
> from all documents that returned in this search.

Not a straight-forward one. You need to change query string as below to handle only name field.

JAVA way:

```
QueryBuilder matchQueryBuilder = 
               QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("elon").defaultField("name");

String[] includeFields = new String[] {"name"};
String[] excludeFields = new String[] {"user"};
sourceBuilder.fetchSource(includeFields, excludeFields);
```

PLAIN:

```
  {
    "_source":
      ["name"],
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "query" : "name:elon"

        }
    }

}
```

And you can do [source controlling in code](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-search.html#_source_filtering) and Hope you are interested in `query_string` way only. If you are open to other ways, you can use [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-search.html)

Then to convert to `List<String>`, you need to iterate the response and add it to a `List`

```
SearchHits hits = searchResponse.getHits();
SearchHit[] searchHits = hits.getHits();
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
for (SearchHit hit : searchHits) {
   Map<String, Object> sourceAsMap = hit.getSourceAsMap();
   names.add(sourceAsMap.get("name"));
}
```

Comment: sir this is returning me nothing. 0 hits.

Comment: Can you add a sample document and mapping for `name` field?

Comment: If you have mapping like `keyword` or `not analyzed` then you may not expect the output as you desired.

Comment: I have not set the maping `keyword` etc . I just simply load data.

Comment: Can you run the below request and add it to the question - `http://host:9200/indexName/_mapping GET`

Comment: please check inn question

Comment: Please add a sample document also from the search query `http://hostNmae:9200/indexName/_search`

Comment: please check now.

Comment: What you have is a nested document - you need to use nested query - refer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31062264/elasticsearch-search-inside-the-array-of-objects]

Comment: And addition to the above comment, java way of doing - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24710831/elasticsearch-java-client-querying-nested-objects